# How to display unchecked data that is not stored in database used laravel?

Tags: arrays, laravel, checkbox

I have 2 tables, namely the Detail Score Table and the Criteria Table.
I used the checked input form to do an assessment. In the assessment input form, there are 17 criteria, the user can make an assessment by checking the checklist.

My code and input form for scoring:

```
public function addScore(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->floor_id == 0) {
            return redirect('pengawas/dashboard')->with('delete','Gagal , Pastikan Gedung dan Lantai Area Kerja Telah Diisi!');
        }

        //dd($totalscore);
        $score_acc = DB::table('scores')
                     ->where('cleaningservices_id','=', $request->input('cleaningservices_id'))
                     ->where(DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(score_dt, '%m'))"),'=', date('m', strtotime(now())))
                     ->sum('total_score');

        $pengawasid = Auth::id();
        $score      = new ScoreModel();
        $totalscore = array_sum($request->input('score'));
        $totalscoreacc = $score_acc + $totalscore;
        $score->user_id                     = $pengawasid;
        $score->cleaningservices_id         = $request->input('cleaningservices_id');
        $score->floor_id                    = $request->input('floor_id');
        $score->total_score                 = $totalscore;
        $score->total_score_accumulation    = $totalscoreacc;
        $score->status_score                = "Bersih";
        $score->save();


        $getscoreid = DB::table('scores')->select('id')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
        //dd($getscoreid);

        //dd($request->score);
        $criteria_ids = $request->criteria_id;
        $scores = $request->score;

        foreach ($scores as $i => $score) {
             $score_detail[] = [
                'score_id'      => $getscoreid->id,
                'criteria_id'   => $request->criteria_id[$i],
                'score'         => $request->score[$score],
                'description'   => $request->description[$i]
             ];
          }

        DetailScoreModel::insert($score_detail);
        return redirect('pengawas/show_scoring')->with('success','Berhasil memberikan penilaian');
    }
```

[image: Form input]

I only save checked criteria with score = 1 into criteria table. Previously I have made, if the checked criteria will have a value of 1, but if unchecked, the score = 0. But if I use this method, every time the user makes an assessment, then 17 new rows will be added. And it's very storage consuming. Therefore, I only store checked ratings into the criteria detail table.

My Code for Show Detail Scoring :

(Database)

[image: Detail Score Table]

(Controller)

```
public function getDetailScorePegawai($id)
        {
            $score     = DB::table('scores')
                        ->select('cleaningservices.id as nip','scores.id as id_score',
                            'scores.*','cleaningservices.*', 'buildings.*','floors.*')
                        ->join('cleaningservices','cleaningservices.id','=','scores.cleaningservices_id')
                        ->join('floors','floors.id','=','scores.floor_id')
                        ->join('buildings','buildings.id','=','floors.building_id')
                        ->where('scores.id','=',$id)
                        ->get();
            $building  = DB::table('buildings')->get();
            $detail_sp = DB::table('detailscores')
                         ->select('detailscores.criteria_id as id_criteria','criterias.*','scores.*','detailscores.*')
                         ->join('criterias','criterias.id','=','detailscores.criteria_id')
                         ->join('scores','scores.id','=','detailscores.score_id')
                         ->where('scores.id','=',$id)
                         ->get();
                         
            return view('pengawas.detail_scorepegawai', compact('score','building','detail_sp','criteria'));
    
        }
```

(View)

```
@foreach($detail_sp as $row)
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="criteria_id[]" value="{{ $row->id_criteria }}">
                                      {{ $row->criteria_name}} : 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="score[{{ $row->id_criteria }}]" id="score" value="1"<?php if($row->score == "1") echo "checked"; ?>>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group input-group mb-3">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description[]" value="{{ $row->description }}">
                                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                                        <div class="input-group-text">
                                                        <span class="fas fa-file-medical"></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              @endforeach
```

[image: Result]

I'm currently having problems, when I create a view for the detailed score. I want to display the detailed score, if score = 1, then checked, if score is not stored in database or 0 then unchecked.

The result I want is like this, this is the result when I save the score in database which is unchecked with score = 0

[image: expect result]

I need your help. Thanks

Comment: 1) There is no code in your question, so a potential answer has to assume a lot of things about your database structure, php code, and html layout. 2) You really should focus your question on what exactly you struggle with! Do you struggle getting the data out of mysql or are you looking for advice on data storage? If not, mysql tag is not relevant.  Do you have a problem iterating through your array of options and comparing those with the array retrieved from mysql? Do you have a problem generating html code?

Comment: Sorry, i've update my question, i've problem when i show Detail Scores.

Comment: try `{ echo "checked=checked"; }}`

Comment: Do you have something like criterias.description on criterias table? In that case you should extract the data from there to present your view.

Comment: The information that you want to present in your view must necessarily be somewhere. If it is not in a table, you will have to hardcode it

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use enum to store all these fields data that could be only one row and one column to store all of those data at once.

it's a better way to go with and save a lot of process and workload.